# Animate a Div Background - CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, jquery-animate

I have a highly optimized page for imaging and some very graphic effects.

I have something I've been trying to do for awhile, and can't find a clear cut answer.

**I want to animate a css background property via jQuery with the same speed as the internal animation (500)**

*Keep in mind, my other animation is imaged based, for good reason with what I'm implementing*

Can I edit the background property of the whole div (as seen on live site) at an animation rate of 500?

http://www.sinsysonline.com/design/index.html

jQuery

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".feat3col").hover(
function() {

$(this).find('img.a').stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "fast");
$(this).css('background', '#000');
},
function() {

$(this).find('img.a').stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
$(this).css('background', '#FFF');
});
});
</script>
```

http://www.sinsysonline.com/design/index.html

Markup:

```
<div class="featured">
            <div class="feat3col">
            <h2>Packages</h2>
                <div class="imgGlow">
                    <img class="a" width:"200px" height:"300px" src="images/filler_200x300.jpg" alt="test" />
                    <img class="b" width:"200px" height:"300px" src="images/filler_200x3002.jpg" alt="test" />
                </div>
            <p>This should extend roughly 5-7 lines. It is simply filler for development purposes. Ignore this statement, and the link below.</p>
            <a href="#" class="botCap">Link Link</a>
        </div>
            <div class="feat3col">
            <h2>Reviews</h2>

                <div class="imgGlow">
                    <img class="a" width:"200px" height:"300px" src="images/filler_200x300.jpg" alt="test" />
                    <img class="b" width:"200px" height:"300px" src="images/filler_200x3002.jpg" alt="test" />
                </div>

            <p>This should extend roughly 5-7 lines. It is simply filler for development purposes. Ignore this statement, and the link below. Make more content!</p>
            <a href="#" class="botCap">Link Link</a>

            </div>
            <div class="feat3col">
            <h2>About</h2>

                <div class="imgGlow">
                    <img class="a" width:"200px" height:"300px" src="images/filler_200x300.jpg" alt="test" />
                    <img class="b" width:"200px" height:"300px" src="images/filler_200x3002.jpg" alt="test" />
                </div>

            <p>This should extend roughly 5-7 lines. It is simply filler for development purposes. Ignore this statement, and the link below. Yet again, these are simply use case scenarios to display different heights and how it still works.</p>
            <a href="#" class="botCap">Link Link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.sinsysonline.com/design/index.html

Keep in mind, if this is a noob question, I've made some sick sites, but had to use plugins. Doing this section 100% solo with my own development. The reason I need to accomplish this in pair with the image is because if I enable transparency on the image it becomes 50kb or so (vs 2-7kb), with optimization and fades, blah blah. I want to be able to utilize this image to make some actual graphic design with a fade, and the whole div to match the background as it fades.

Comment: can you try using background position plugin http://keith-wood.name/backgroundPos.html

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173719/jquery-background-position-animation-with-css-sprites-not-working/15174668#15174668 it might be helpful for you

Comment: Both of these answers require plug ins. I'm trying to avoid that. Is there really nothing to animate in jQuery other than position and opacity?

Answer (score 1):

Skip jQuery and just use css:

```
.feat3col{
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s;
    transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
.feat3col img.a {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.feat3col:hover{
    background-color: #000;
}
.feat3col:hover img.a {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use jQuery, then just call animate on the image opacity, and pass in options where a step/progress function is used.  inside the step/progress function, do whatever you want to animate other stuff at the same rate as the opacity, but you need to handle calculating the colors yourself.  Obviously white to black and back to white is simple.

jQuery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".feat3col").hover(

    function () {

        $(this).find('img.a').finish().animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            progress: function (animation, p, remainingMs) {
                var c = parseInt(255 - (p * 255));
                $(this).closest('.feat3col')
                   .css('background-color', 'rgb('+c+','+c+','+c+')');
                // do other animation stuffs
            }
        })
    },

    function () {

        $(this).find('img.a').finish().animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            progress: function (animation, p, remainingMs) {
                var c = parseInt(p * 255);
                $(this).closest('.feat3col')
                   .css('background-color', 'rgb('+c+','+c+','+c+')');
                // do other animation stuffs
            }
        })
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rW3FC/

Comment: This is the way to go, particularly since you've said your site is highly optimized. JS consumes more resources than css, so most people tend to go to js/jQuery only if it can't be done with css. There're also other animations you can do with css, like scale, rotate, and fading colors, among others.

Comment: You could also take the image, crop out the unused parts, change the white to transparent, and reduce the color pallete to 32 colors, and the image will be ~23k.  Still bigger than your 8k original, but still pretty small PNG.  You could also make it a .GIF file, with some quick editting, it turned out to be ~11k.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can animate the background via jQuery.  What you could do is put another img or div  behind the other content and fade it in and out as necessary to sort of fake an animated background.

Comment: *sigh* I was already scared to do that... I already did that once, which is bad-ish practice. Maybe a css animate solution then?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sinsysonline.com/design/index.html

Solution:
jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".feat3col").hover(
function() {

$(this).find('img.a').stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, 500);
},
function() {

$(this).find('img.a').stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, 500);
});
});
</script>
```

Solution:
CSS

```
.feat3col:hover {
-webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
background:#EEE;
border-radius:50px;
```

}